# Null object reference while get last messages from channel object - Twilio programmable chat Android SDK

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

So it's about getting,

`java.lang.NullPointerException`

while using Twilio programable chat SDK in Android

I have one fragment where I am getting the list of the channel, On the click of the particular channel I am passing the channel sid from fragment to activity and in the activity, I am getting the channel from client again by using that sid, but when I am trying to get last messages from the channel then I am getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.twilio.chat.Messages.getLastMessages(int, com.twilio.chat.CallbackListener)' on a null object reference
```

And the mystery is When I use "attach a debugger to the android process",  I can see the error I can get object and messages also with debugger on. I believe this is something to do with threading.

**Here is the code**

```
myChannel.getMessages().getLastMessages(50, new CallbackListener<List<Message>>() {
                          @Override
                          public void onSuccess(List<Message> messages) {
                              mMessagesAdapter.setMessages(mMessages);
                              setMessageInputEnabled(true);
                              mWriteMessageEditText.requestFocus();
                          }

                          @Override
                          public void onError(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
                              Log.e(TAG, "error" + errorInfo.getMessage());

                          }
                      });
```

Also, I came to know with the doc of Twilio that, I have to use synchronized method over the Channel object. with the method **"myChannel.getMessages()"**.
doc-link: [URL](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/chat/releases/4.0.2/docs/classcom_1_1twilio_1_1chat_1_1Channel.html#ae45ecf4af3a03a83d3e65ccca76b398b)
I am attaching a screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks9bn.png)

And I believe I have to do synchronization first with using some method, but I do not see any method for that.
How can I synchronize? What code Should I use?

Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: First join() on channel then you can use this inside status listener

Comment: I tried in that way, it gives me member already exist  error because i already joined in previous fragment

Comment: Did you check synchronization status before calling getMessages()?

Comment: Yes, it's giving me com.twilio.chat.Channel.SynchronizationStatus.ALL =(3)

Comment: I implement the getChannelMessage function in onSynchronizationChanged method if (mChannel.getSynchronizationStatus() == Channel.SynchronizationStatus.ALL), now it's working but it's taking time